# how to Localize audio file in windows phone?

Tags: xaml, localization, windows-phone-7.1, converters

I am trying to localize my .wav audio file. i am getting the exception like this:

```
MS.Internal.Data.DynamicValueConverter' converter failed to convert value 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream' (type 'System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream');
BindingExpression: Path='LocalizedResources.AudioTest' DataItem='WPLocalizationMultilingualAppToolkit.LocalizedStrings' (HashCode=77186600);
target element is 'System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement' (Name='AudioTestElement'); 
target property is 'Source' (type 'System.Uri').. System.InvalidOperationException: Can't convert type System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream to type System.Uri.
```

How can I convert `UnmanagedMemoryStream` to Uri?